# How can I convert Long[] to IEnumerable<long?>

Tags: c#

I am getting an exception of

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'long[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<long?>'

How can I resolve this issue?

I have tried this but doesnot work.

the AssignedPlayerSites is an IList property.

```
IEnumerable<long?> multipleSelectedSites = cmsUser.AssignedPlayerSites.Select(ps => ps.Id).AsEnumerable<long?>();
```

Comment: Just curious on the use of nullable. If no id is matched, the collection should made empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you can't convert from `IEnumerable<long>` to `IEnumerable<long?>` in this way. You can do this using the [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) extension method, e.g.:

```
var longArray = new long[] { 1, 2, 3 };
IEnumerable<long?> nullableLongEnumerable = longArray.Cast<long?>();

IEnumerable<long?> multipleSelectedSites =
      cmsUser.AssignedPlayerSites.Select(ps => ps.Id).Cast<long?>();
```

However, depending on what you're doing with it, this might make more sense:

```
IEnumerable<long> multipleSelectedSites = cmsUser.AssignedPlayerSites.Select(ps => ps.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to convert `long[]` to `IEnumarable<long?>` instead of creating `long?[]` at the beginning. It will work fine without converting if it's already `long?[]`

But in case `long[]` is a return type of a method that you cannot modify, you can use [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) method to convert it:

```
IEnumerable<long?> multipleSelectedSites = cmsUser.AssignedPlayerSites.Cast<long?>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
long[] items = new long[] { 1, 2, 3 };
IEnumerable<long?> castedItems = items.Select<long, long?>(x =>
                                 {
                                     if (object.Equals(x, null))
                                            return null;
                                        else
                                            return x;
                                 });
```

what it does is I select the item in the collection, evaluate if it's null and then return the value needed.

1 point of concern though, since your data type in the array is `long`, I see no point of checking if It's null because thats impossible for that data type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no casting needed. Simply replace this:

```
IEnumerable<long?> multipleSelectedSites = cmsUser.AssignedPlayerSites
                                         .Select(ps => ps.Id).AsEnumerable<long?>();
```

with this:

```
IEnumerable<long?> multipleSelectedSites = cmsUser.AssignedPlayerSites
                                         .Select(ps => new long?(ps.Id)).AsEnumerable();
```